# Variable of type Long is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, long-integer, requiredfieldvalidator, required

I have one ViewModel that has property Id of type `long` without attribute `[required]`. This model I use for search.

Problem : Why always when i try to make search request and input for property `Id` leave empty i get validation error as `Id field is required` ?

Comment: `long`'s are not `nullable` so you need to supple a value. Make it nullable `long?` and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your model property `nullable`.

```
public long? myprop { get; set; }
```